# Modal popup extender losing ID

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Edit:**

Added onload method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["usersName"] != null)
        {

            object a = Session["_id"];

            IDMaster = Convert.ToInt32(a);

            GridView1.Columns[10].Visible = true;
            GridView1.Columns[11].Visible = true;


        }
```

I'm using a modal pop up extender to warn my customers that the item amount of a specific item is over a certain amount.

I have two buttons within this extender that allows a user to confirm they want an email sending to them when new stock arrives or not.

The trigger for the 'yes' button works perfectly but when i send the row ID to the constructor of my class used to store the email details it is always set to 0, even though the variable is global.

Here is my code to explain the issue further:

Button within my modal to add items to the cart:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {


        GridViewRow row = ((Button)sender).Parent.Parent as GridViewRow;
        TextBox t = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtQuan");

        *********Gain the item row ID (this is what needs to be passed*******
        object ID = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;

        *********This ID should be passed but is setting to 0************
        rowID = Convert.ToInt32(ID);

        string qty = t.Text;

        int stockToAdd = Convert.ToInt32(qty);

        DBHandler add = new DBHandler(rowID);

        int qtyCheck = add.getStockQty();

        if (stockToAdd > qtyCheck)
        {

            Button2_ModalPopupExtender.Show();

        }

        else{


            SqlConnection con;
            con = add.openDB();

            con.Open();

            DBHandler idCheck = new DBHandler(rowID);
            int rows = idCheck.checkCartRows();

            if (rows > 0)
            {

               int qtyNow = idCheck.getCartQty();

                int updateStock = qtyNow + stockToAdd;

                idCheck.updateQty(rowID, updateStock);
                updatePanel();

            }

            else
            {

                idCheck.insertCart(qty);
                updatePanel();

            }
            add.close();

        }


        }
```

The following code shows my confirm onclick button method. Note the ID 'rowID' that was stored in the above method when the add to cart button was clicked. This rowID is is setting to 0 instead of holding the rowID value.

```
 protected void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       ***** rowID is setting to 0*******
        DBoutOfStockEmail insertNewEmailDetail = new DBoutOfStockEmail(IDMaster, rowID);

        DBMembershipHandler getEmail = new DBMembershipHandler(IDMaster);

        string emailToSend = getEmail.emailOfMember();

        insertNewEmailDetail.insertDetails(emailToSend);

    }
```

**To summaries this question: Why is the rowID variable setting to '0' when i click the yes button with the modal pop up extender?**

Comment: This can be from several things.. are you checking or doing `IsPostBack` checks, are you holding the Value(s) in a `Session` Variable..? `ViewState is it enabled or disabled..?` can you show what your `Page_Load Event` Looks like

Comment: also why don't you change this line `object ID = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;` to this `var ID = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;` also there are so many potential `Memory Leaks` in your current code ` DBHandler` where are you `Releasing` this object..?

Comment: make sure the `LinkButton1` doesn't cause `PostBack` remember `Page_Load` gets called on every `PostBack`

Comment: @DJ KRAZE many thanks for your answers. I am only holiding my member ID in a session. Im simply trying to hold the value of the row ID between button clicks. I will add my page load even to the code above.

Comment: you need to check `if(!IsPostBack){}` or `if(IsPostBack){}` depending on how you want to populate / retrieve the stored information does this make sense..?

Comment: @DJ KRAZE I have managed to sort this by using a viewstate object to store the ID then retrieve it when my modal button event is triggered. You were right, it was the postback causing the loss of the ID var. Many thanks. Could you please copy your answer into the answer box so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Yes this is a common oversight that many forget to `utilize || Check`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my initial Comment I am going to post this as an answer

> This can be from several things.. are you checking or doing IsPostBack checks, are you holding the Value(s) in a Session Variable..? ViewState is it enabled or disabled..? can you show what your Page_Load Event Looks like